# How to remove the /******/ comments in webpack / babel

Tags: javascript, webpack, minify, babeljs, npm-scripts

I'm trying to use babel to compile my javascript , and unless I use the `--optimize-minimize` flag (or `-p`), every single line has these `/******/` comments.

How do I get rid of all comments?

I'm kicking it off with an npm script: `"build:dev": "webpack -d --env=dev --config ./webpack.config.dev.js",`

and my `webpack.config.dev.js` looks like:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (env) => {
    return {
        entry: './src/js/index.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'js/path.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/static')
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: i guess you could do `'/*****/'.replace('')`

Comment: There's gotta be some kind of config option to not render all this, no? It doesn't happen if I do `-p` - only problem is it minfiies it all